# Remove spaces from tag value using ctrl + h regex(prefered) or xslt

Tags: regex, xml

I'm using Notepad++ and want to do some change on xslt transformation result.
I need to change this:

```
<MFPRN>12 005 01</MFPRN>
```

into this::

```
<MFPRN>1200501</MFPRN>
```

Dunno much about regex, but know how to use Ctrl+h :)
regards
Michał

Comment: it doesn't work that way, you have got to show the full file structure, otherwise you can just replace space by empty , isn't it ? You need to show sample strcutreu of your xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to find regexp **(>\d+)\s+**

and replace with **\1** couple of times.

[image]